# await Task.Run does not actually wait

Tags: c#, async-await

I am trying to get my head around the async-await however I wrote a small test and cannot understand the results i am getting.

Consider the following code (WPF Application, inside MainWindow):

```
private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Stopwatch l_Stopwatch = new Stopwatch();

    Debug.WriteLine("Entering Button_Click...");

    l_Stopwatch.Start();

    await DoSomethingAsync();

    l_Stopwatch.Stop();

    Debug.WriteLine("DoSomethingAsync completed in {0}", l_Stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds);

    l_Stopwatch.Restart();

    await DoSomethingElseAsync();

    l_Stopwatch.Stop();

    Debug.WriteLine("DoSomethingElseAsync completed in {0}", l_Stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
}

private async Task DoSomethingAsync()
{
    Debug.WriteLine("Doing something Async");

    await Task.Delay(5000);

}

private async Task DoSomethingElseAsync()
{
    await Task.Run((Action)(async () => { 
        Debug.WriteLine("Doing something else Async");

        await Task.Delay(5000);
    }));
}
```

i would expect DoSomethingElseAsync to wait ~5000ms before continuing, however I keep getting the following

```
Entering Button_Click...
Doing something Async
DoSomethingAsync completed in 5005
Doing something else Async
DoSomethingElseAsync completed in 3
```

So at this point I think there is something fundamental that I am not understanding of the async-await way...

Can anyone shed light?

Comment: The culprit is your cast to `Action`. Leave it out and you'll get the overload that takes a `Func<Task>`, which duly awaits the task. (Note that wrapping the whole thing in `Task.Run` is pointless overhead, but I assume this is for fun and giggles only, since you already have `DoSomethingAsync`.)

Comment: Yes, I am trying to understand by fiddling around, now as you said removing the cast does actually work as expected, but i am still confused why...as both Task.Run(Action) and Task.Run(Func<Task>) both return Task. Should not the "await" wait for the action or the function to complete? As I said i might be missing something fundamental, but I have been reading Stephen Cleary and other papers and still dont seem to understand...

Comment: The difference is that you create radically different tasks this way -- the overload taking an `Action` will run the synchronous part of the task (`Debug.WriteLine`), then get a task that pauses for 5 seconds and *throw it away* (since `Action` does not return anything), so it's "done". The overload that takes a `Func<Task>` actually uses the result (by awaiting it). What you are awaiting in both cases is the wrapping task you created, not the inner task.

Comment: Maybe I start to understand, I kept (Action) from my old synchronous calls, then just added async and await all the way through. However, while (Action)() => makes a lambda that returns nothing,  async () => make a lambda that returns Task, so Task.Run actually becomes Task<Task> Task.Run() rather than Task Task.Run(). Or am I saying something wrong?
EDIT: Because the confusing part is actually the Intellisense tip for the overloads, in both cases of Task.Run(Action action) and Task.Run(Funct<Task> Function) it suggests to use the await (overload 1 of 6 and overload 3 of 6) on VS 2013 Express

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
await Task.Run((Action)(async () => { 
    Debug.WriteLine("Doing something else Async");

    await Task.Delay(5000);
}));
```

You cast to `Action` delegate which doesn't return anything and cannot be awaited (there is no `Task` to await because `Action` returns `void`).

In your case you can simply change code to:

```
await Task.Run(async () => { 
    Debug.WriteLine("Doing something else Async");

    await Task.Delay(5000);
});
```

**OR**

you can cast to `Func<Task>` delegate which returns `Task` that can be awaited:

```
await Task.Run((Func<Task>)(async () => { 
    Debug.WriteLine("Doing something else Async");

    await Task.Delay(5000);
}));
```

**Additional info:**

If you see compiler generated code ([SharpLab](https://sharplab.io/#v2:CYLg1APgAgDABFAjAbgLAChYMQOgCICWAhgOYB2A9gM4AuBAxlWpvEgKzMZQDMCATHADCcAN4Y4EhLygAOBADY4AFQCmtAOoEaACwoBXGoKK0CZEgAoAlOMlj0khwgCcCnACU9Zc7LhW4AXgA+Z1c8FQAbIgBPc0RLS2YHAF8bCVSpBDkoRVUNLW0jEzMlCiQ+K3S7R0koF2z3T3NvRD5Lbzk/IJD6sMiYuPjEySS0+0l0nkyFZTUaTR1CumLStgqxiSrq7vkGr282AB5swLafTuDa0Ijo2PiE9JG4DBT0dIwMIA)) you will get differences:

- When you cast to `Action` compiler creates `AsyncVoidMethodBuilder`
- When you cast to `Func<Task>` or do not cast at all compiler creates
  `AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`